# UITextField and UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel

There is a textField and a button in my view, and if the 
textfield is empty I do not want to user can click the button.
When user text something in the textfield, the button will bu
clickable.
How can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your UITextField, you can set:

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(editing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEditingEvents];
```

Then in your editing: have:

```
-(void)editing:(UITextField *)sender {
    myButton.enabled = ![sender.text isEqualToString:@""];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Listen for changes to the text field. As the text changes, update the button's `enabled` property based on whether there is text or not. Of course you also need to set the button's state at the beginning as well.

```
// Setup the text field change listener (this can be done in IB if appropriate)
// Put this in viewDidLoad if not using IB.
UITextField *myTextField = ... // a reference to the text field
[myTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldChangedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

// Initialize the button's state (put this in viewDidLoad)
myButton.enabled = myTextField.text.length > 0;

// The method called as the text changes in the text field
- (void)textFieldChangedAction:(UITextField *)sender {
    myButton.enabled = sender.text.length > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can "hide" the button by setting the alpha value of the button to 0 and when the textfield is at least one character long, then set the button's alpha value to 1 to "show" the button. I think this conceptually is easy to do and very presentable to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Set the  textfield.delegate to self
Then in delegate that is textfielddidbeginediting 
(
Check is textfield is @""
Then disable the button

Else
Enable the button
)

And there is one more. Delegate u can use

Textdidchangecharacters

And in viewdidload first state of the button should be disabled